# При выборе в select пункта, если data-price заполнено, то выводим блок и берем цену из выбранного пункта и выводим в блоке, как сделать?

Tags: javascript

При выборе в select пункта, если data-price заполнено, то выводим блок и берем цену из выбранного пункта и выводим в блоке, если цена не заполнена, то блок не выводим, скрываем.

Я тут сделал что смог, но не все, как сделать такую проверку, если есть цена то показываем блок, если нет то не показываем.

Вот тут я не могу допетрить как сделать проверку
['1'].includes(price) ? $('#priceBlock').show() : $('#priceBlock').hide();

```js
$('#priceAll').change(function() {
  $('div.priceBlock').slideUp();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#priceAll').change(function() {
    //let dateNauchet = $(this).data("price");
    let price = $('#priceAll option:selected').data('price'); //берем цену из дата
    console.log(price);
    $("#sum").html(price); //выводим сумму
    ['1'].includes(price) ? $('#priceBlock').show() : $('#priceBlock').hide(); //тут проверка, если есть что-то в data-price то показываем блок, если нет, то скрываем
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="priceAll">
  <option data-price="" value="Mini">Mini</option>
  <option data-price="14800" value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
  <option data-price="21800" value="Basic">Basic</option>
  <option data-price="32800" value="Premium">Premium</option>
</select>

<br />

<div id="priceBlock" class="ac-custom mrtb" style="display:none">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="nauchet" id="nauchet" value="Да" />
    <label for="nauchet"><span>Диагностическая карта для постановки на учёт <strong id="sum"></strong> руб</span></label>
  </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение.

```js
$('#priceAll').change(function() {
  $('div.priceBlock').slideUp();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#priceAll').change(function() {
    let price = $('#priceAll option:selected').data('price'); //берем цену из дата
    $("#sum").html(price); //выводим сумму
    (price != "") ? $('#priceBlock').show() : $('#priceBlock').hide(); //тут проверка, если есть что-то в data-price то показываем блок, если нет, то скрываем
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="priceAll">
  <option data-price="" value="Mini">Mini</option>
  <option data-price="14800" value="Minimum">Minimum</option>
  <option data-price="21800" value="Basic">Basic</option>
  <option data-price="32800" value="Premium">Premium</option>
</select>

<br />

<div id="priceBlock" class="ac-custom mrtb" style="display:none">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="nauchet" id="nauchet" value="Да" />
    <label for="nauchet"><span>Диагностическая карта для постановки на учёт <strong id="sum"></strong> руб</span></label>
  </li>
</div>
```